# What query language does NOSQL database uses? Can anyone explains what is unstructured database?

Tags: nosql, bigdata

I 'm very eager to find people saying Big data and NOSQL database. I was really surprised with terminology like Unstructured data.. What does it really mean? Some say schema-less. Then, can you explain how data is actually stored in a database..? Please clarify how we retrieve data from big data and Store values in big data as its type is unstructured?

I want to learn NOSQL database queries on my own.. Is it possible to install NOSQL database in my ACER lap with 200 GB HDD?

Answer (score 0):

*Unstructured data* means there is no well-defined arrangement to the data. It's does not have an underlying type that describes all the data. It does not have structure that is present in all records across the data set.

Depending on a database, unstructured data may be stored as string, byte array or something more exotic. It shouldn't really matter to you as a user of that database.

> Is that possible to install NOSQL database ...

Yes, it is. There are many databases that you could install. Maybe you can read [NoSql distilled](http://martinfowler.com/books/nosql.html) book first, to get ideas of what NoSql really is? You can also see [nosql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nosql/info) for some pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and Recommendation of NoSql distilled book. Is there any specific query languages available like SQL or We can use SQL in NoSql databases

Comment: Yes there is. Unlike in RDBMS, where SQL-like languages dominate, in NoSQL world there are many languages. Some of them like SQL, some are rather different. Sample languages are CQL, restful queries, custom queries languages for graph database. Basically each db has its own query language.

Comment: Yeah NoSql distilled book is very interestinng